# Converting a Scheme constant that is bound to a function into equivalent Common Lisp

Tags: scheme

I am converting some Scheme code to Common Lisp. I don't know Scheme. I know a bit of Common Lisp.

First, the Scheme code defines a variable (or is it a constant?) whose value is the name of a function:

```
(define alert-propagator alert-propagators)
```

Here is the function:

```
(define (alert-propagators propagators)
    ...)
```

The function is then indirectly called, by referencing the constant:

```
(alert-propagator arg)
```

That's pretty slick.

I am wondering if this is also possible in Common Lisp? Here's what I tried: First, I defined a constant and bound it to a function:

```
(defconstant alert-propagator #'alert-propagators)
```

Then I defined the function:

```
(defun alert-propagators (propagators)
    ...)
```

Fine.

But now, in order to indirectly invoke the function (via the constant), I must use funcall:

```
(funcall alert-propagator arg)
```

I think that kind of defeats the whole purpose of defining the constant (abstraction). What I really want is to be able to simply write:

```
(alert-propagator arg)
```

Is there a way to accomplish this in Common Lisp?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Common Lisp is a LISP2 and it that means there are different namespaces for identifiers in operator position and identifiers in other positions.

```lisp
(defun square (x)
  (* x x))

(defparameter square 10) ; unconventional, should be *square*

(square square) ; ==> 100
```

This cannot be done in Scheme since with `(square square)` both of the `square` identifiers point to the exact same object. It might be a function (procedure in Scheme speak) that takes a function as argument.

You can get objects from the function name space by using `(function square)` or the syntactic sugar short form `#'square`, thus you can get the actual function bound in the function namespace as a value.

You can also get the function namespace value with `symbol-function` such that `(symbol-function 'square)` evaluates to the same function as `#'square` does. This has the feature that it can work as a `setf` place, opening for setting something in the function namespace to a value. It only works if the second argument actually is a function:

```lisp
(setf (symbol-function 'test) #'square)
(test square) ; ==> 100
```

`defconstant`, `defparameter` and `defvar` does not set anything in the function namespace. Thay can only be used as normal variables that you can also use for functions that can be applies with `funcall` and `apply`.

You should refrain from using `defconstant` for everything else than values that would be true to the end of time as the system is allowed to inline and thus changing a constant might not affect the code unless you reread and recompile. In all practical purposes using `defparameter` and proper `+NAMING-CONVENTION+` would work for semi constants like `+VAT+` that might change next year!

Scheme does not have constants, but the zero environment in R5RS is expected to work the same way with the data the original procedures worked with so that constant folding using the original versions won't break anything. With R6RS (and possibly R7RS) imported forms cannot be overridden, even from other import statements. In Scheme you don't redefine with `define` but with `set!` just as you can use `setf` and `setq` to set variables that you have made with `defparamater` or `defvar` in Common Lisp.